# How to add style in functions.php depending on conditions?

Tags: php, categories, css, embed

I'm a newbie for coding,
I would like to learn how to add css style conditionally in functions.php
My header controlled by `.header-outer` class. What would it be the best way to add css depending on category?
I was able to determine category slug (not standard wordpress category) and wrote some if conditions. It's working but could not understand adding css.
With `wp_enqueue_style` should I call external predefined css files or is it possible to write directly in functions.php.

```
wp_enqueue_style( '***', get_template_directory_uri() . '/mycss/category1.css', array(), '1.1', 'all');
```

Here I could not understand the first *** part ? I would like to embed all style not a class.

Thank you,
Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to add a external css to your head.

```
//Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
```

Comment: Thank you, it has worked like this...(It was for Easy Digital Downloads Categories) `$terms = get_the_terms($download->ID, 'download_category');
$category = array_slice($terms, -1);
foreach ( $category as $term )  { $slug .= $term->slug; }
switch ($slug){
 case 'home' :
        wp_enqueue_style( 'home', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/default.css', false, '1.0', 'all' ); 
        break;
    case 'photoshop' : 
        wp_enqueue_style( 'photoshop', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/photoshop.css', false, '1.0', 'all' ); 
        break;`

Comment: Your welcome. Please let otherw know that this is resolved bij giving it a check en points up

Answer (score 0):

So on your category page check the body tag in your developer tools. There should be a category class. You can then target that page in your CSS with that classname. This is standard CSS stuff.

```
.cat-name{ color: blue; }
```

All other pages will not have that classname and the `color:` rule be your default.

Answering your direct question on how to conditionally load a stylesheet:

```
if(is_category('cats')){ 
    wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesheet-name', get_template_directory_uri() .'/mycss/category1.css', array(), '1.1', 'all');
}
```

Remember categories and taxonomies can get pretty complex. Custom taxonomies and categories may not work with something as simple as `is_category`

Comment: If using the last option `is_category('cats')` you'll most likely need to wrap in `get_header` or `template_redirect` otherwise it doesn't always work.

Comment: Interesting, I've never ran into that and am using this code within functions.php currently. However as mentioned in my answer WP categories and taxonomies are tricky.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're trying to say that you want to show a different css file for every category you have in your website.

If that is the case, you will simply hook to `wp_enqueue_scripts` and check if this is a category template using `is_category()` and which category is this using `get_the_category()`, and load the corresponding stylesheet.

Let's assume you have the files named with the same slug of the categories (i.e. photoshop -> photoshop.css, etc.):

```
function wpse220214_enqueue_category_style() {
    if(is_category()) {
        $slug = get_the_category(get_query_var( 'cat' ));
        $url = get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/css/categories/$slug.css";
        if(file_exists($url)) { //So you don't get errors if the file is missing
            wp_enqueue_style( "$slug-style", $url, array(), '1.0');
        }
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse220214_enqueue_category_style');
```

**Edit**: You mentioned that you are using a custom taxonomy, 'download_category' as I see in your comments. In this case we will use `is_tax()` and [`get_queried_object()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) instead:

```
function wpse220214_enqueue_download_category_style() {
    if(is_tax('download_category')) {
        $slug = get_queried_object()->slug;
        $url = get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/css/categories/$slug.css";
        if(file_exists($url)) { //So you don't get errors if the file is missing
            wp_enqueue_style( "$slug-style", $url, array(), '1.0');
        }
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse220214_enqueue_download_category_style');
```

Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12289287/2931528) for using `get_queried_object()` and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8832952/2931528) for `get_query_var('cat')`.